# How to load simple product images on configurable product in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, product-images, configurable-swatches

**How we can show the images on page when load of simple product of configurable product**.

**By default configurable product image show but what i want when we click on color option then its associated simple product should show without click it should be on page load**.

These should be shown vertically besides main image as it does magento on swatch click but i want on page load.

Comment: hey did you find a solution for it?

Comment: I'm also looking for a workaround.